# How to choose a one or two-parted word(name) from file without "|" separator in python

Tags: python, string, random, format, readline

Hello i'm looking for solution to solve my problem:

I have text file *countries-and-capitals.txt* with example words:

> Poland | Warsaw
> Sri Lanka | Colombo

and i need to write code that will pick a random name of Country or Capital.

My problem is that i can't figure out how to pick in example **Sri Lanka** without "**|**" separator and without **Colombo** word.

I've stuck on

```
import random

word = random.choice(open("countries-and-capitals.txt").readlines())
```

but this code picks whole line with "\n".

Comment: Use `word.split("|")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Ka-Wa Yip](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4143312/ka-wa-yip) [BrokenBenchmark](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17769815/brokenbenchmark) [Devang Sanghani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5833865/devang-sanghani)

With you guys i've found solution to pick randomly: country or capital

```
import random

word = random.choice(open("countries-and-capitals.txt").readlines())
word = word.strip('\n').split(" | ")
word = random.choice(word[0:2])
print(word)
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can use list unpacking as well as `.split()` to handle this in one line:

```py
import random

file = open("countries-and-capitals.txt")
[country, capital] = random.choice(file.readlines()).split(" | ")
file.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's say you want to pick Sri Lanka:

```
import random
word = random.choice(open("countries-and-capitals.txt").readlines())
word = word.split(" | ")
country = 'Sri Lanka'
if word[0] == country:
    print("Sri Lanka's capital is: "+word[1].strip())
```

You can use split("|") to remove `|`, and `.strip()` to remove `\n`.

*Output:*

[image]

If you want to just print random country or capital, you can apply another random generator:

```
import random
word = random.choice(open("countries-and-capitals.txt").readlines())
word = word.split(" | ") #remove |
word[1] = word[1].strip() #remove \n
print(random.sample(word, 1)[0])
```

*Output:*

[image]

Comment: Program have to print country or capital, how to implement random choice to your code between word[0] and word[1]?

Comment: @Deadjim use `random.sample` to `word`. See my updated answer.

Comment: i think i've found solution with adding next line: `word = random.choice(word[0:2])`